# Passing a variable into str.match to segment a string into desired lengths

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

I have looked at many of the posts involving this kind of question but I have not been able to find anything that works in this situation.

I have a variable x, it is an integer given the following value.

`let x = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(characterNumber));`

My goal is to segment a string into array elements of the desired length. Using integers I can do so like the following.

`let secondMessage = newMessage.match(/.{1,3}/g);`

My ideal solution would be for the following to work, however whatever I am trying returns as null. In my code editor, when I pass anything that is not an integer (x in this case) the colour of the inside {} changes.

`let secondMessage = newMessage.match(/.{1,x}/g);`

I have tried creating a RegExp, however that also returns null.

Thank you for any answers and sorry for the long (possibly repeated) question.

Comment: It should work with `RegExp`. Can you show your attempt using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside regular expressions. You need to construct the regular expression dynamically by creating a string and then calling `new RegExp()`.

```js
let x = 3;
let rx = new RegExp(`.{1,${x}}`, 'g');
let newMessage = 'abcdefghij';
let secondMessage = newMessage.match(rx);
console.log(secondMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your response ;) really appreciate it! Would you be able to explain to me the flags you used in the RegExp? ``` (`.{1,${x}}`, 'g') ``` I've been reading the MDN pages but cant make hide not hair of it. Thanks again!

Comment: Unforunately I am below 15 reputation so I cannot publicly upvote your comment, but I certainly tried!

Comment: The `g` flag is the same as `/g` in your regexp, it means to match all the occurrences of the pattern.

Comment: `\`.{1,${x}}\`` is an ECMAScript 6 template literal, it allows you to write strings with variable substitutions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Amazing thank you for the information and the link =) First few times using stack so sorry about that! Answer accepted! Thanks again!